# My view isn't rendering any result in the template - django

Tags: django, django-views

I'm working on a Django project and i'm quite the beginner so i'm really sorry if this is a basic question, my view isn't showing any result in the template,
here's my view:

```
def all_products(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    context = {'products': products}
    return render(request, 'users/home.html', context)
```

this is the model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)  
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    price = models.FloatField(null=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(null=True)
    category =models.ForeignKey(Category,related_name='products',on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    developer = models.ForeignKey(Developer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

and finally this is the part of html needed:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center" >

    {% for product in products %}
    <div class="col-auto mb-3"> 
    <div class="card mx-0" style="width: 12rem; height:21rem; background-color: black;">
        <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top img-fluid" style="width: 12rem; height:16rem;" src="{{ product.picture.url}}" alt="Card image cap"></a>
        <div class="card-block">
         <a href="#"><h5 class="card-title mt-1 mb-0" style="color:white; font-size: 18px; font-family: 'Segoe UI';"><b>{{product.title}}</b></h5><a href="#"></a>
            <p class="card-text text-muted mb-1" style="color:white;">{{product.developer.title}}</p>
             <p class="item-price card-text text-muted"><strike >$25.00</strike> <b style="color:white;"> {{product.price}} </b></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
        
    {% endfor %}
 </div>
```

I also do have some product objects in my database, so where could the problem be?

Comment: is anything showing on your page, like is the html even loading?

Comment: @Henty yes the template loads, and shows all other parts properly, except this one

Comment: Sorry i don't think i can help, all i can suggest is debugging yourself. Don't see anything else unless you're Product query isn't returning anything

Comment: i'm very sorry to ask this, but do you have any tutorial on how i can debug in django? i never did that before so i'm kinda having a hard time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```html
<center>
<div class="row justify-content-center" >

    {% for product in products %}
    <div class="col-auto mb-3">
    <div class="card mx-0" style="width: 12rem; height:21rem; background-color: black;">
        <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top img-fluid" style="width: 12rem; height:16rem;" src="{{ product.picture.url }}" alt="Card image cap"></a>
        <div class="card-block">
         <a href="#"><h5 class="card-title mt-1 mb-0" style="color:white; font-size: 18px; font-family: 'Segoe UI';"><b>{{ product.title }}</b></h5><a href="#"></a>
            <p class="card-text text-muted mb-1" style="color:red;">{{ product.developer.name }}</p> # Here I putted 'name' but probably you'll put 'title'; depends on model Developer!
             <p class="item-price card-text text-muted"><strike>$ 25.00</strike> <b style="color:red;"> ${{ product.price }} </b></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    {% endfor %}
 </div>
</center>
```

In the urls.py of the project:

```py
"""teste URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('core.urls')),
]
```

In the urls.py of the app:

```py
from django.urls import path
from .views import *


urlpatterns = [
    path('products/', all_products, name='products')
]
```

And to show the image I had to install **dj_static** and put in wsgi.py:

```py
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from dj_static import Cling, MediaCling

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'test.settings')

application = Cling(MediaCling(get_wsgi_application()))
```

Comment: yes that's primarely how it's supposed to look, but ofc with as many products as there are in the database

Comment: Ok, I'll put in the answer what I did maybe it helps you!

Comment: Try now! To be honest there is no problem with your views and models; or at least I didn't see anything!

Comment: after doing that and running the server, it throws me a 404 not found, is there anything i'm missing?

Comment: Did you just changed the style to red? Or did you installed the dj_static? Wasn't supposed to throw this error since you only chaged the style

Comment: i installed dj_static too, since changing the color alone didn't solve the problem

Comment: So I do not know what it is! The code that you gave are ok; maybe there is some problem out of the code that you putted in the question! Sorry!

Comment: Did you add anything to urls.py?

Comment: Hmm sorry! I forgot to delete something that I putted in the href of the img ({% url 'index' %}); Yes, I had to create a urls.py, I'll put in the 'answer' what I did!

Comment: thank you very much omg that was what i missed! 
i needed to update my urls
thank you very much!